# mv in for loop : "when moving multiple files last argument must be a directory"

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I try to rename  few files, omitting the first n characters. In fact I want to remove the `[ www.blabla.com ]` prefix (18 chars).

I'm on windows, using bash command on Git-bash.

I've tried this command :

```
for f in *blabla*; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed -e 's/^...................//'); done
```

But I've the error:

> when moving multiple files last argument must be a directory"

But my understanding is that I already do the mv one by one

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33947738/7552 -- please don't post the same question to multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

Double quote was missing :

```
for f in *blabla*; do 
    mv "$f" $(echo $f | sed -e 's/^...................//');
done
```